# How to pass a generic type in a React component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a component that takes an array of options which is defined as follows:

```
interface Props {
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: string;
  }[]
}
function MyComponent(props: Props) {...}
```

And implemented like this:

```
<MyComponent
  options={[
    { label: "Right Hand", value: "RIGHT" },
    { label: "Left Hand", value: "LEFT" }
  ]}
/>
```

In this example I give options to select a dominant hand and I've defined a type for that like this:

```
type DominantHand = "RIGHT" | "LEFT"
```

Is it possible to make `MyComponent` flexible to specify the type of options?

I've tried to accomplish this like the following but obviously the syntax isn't correct here:

```
type DominantHand = "RIGHT" | "LEFT"
type Gender = "MALE" | "FEMALE"

interface Props {
  options<T>: { // this syntax is wrong
    label: string;
    value: T;
  }[]
}
function MyComponent(props: Props) {...}

...

<MyComponent
  options<DominantHand>={[ // <--- this syntax is wrong
    { label: "Right Hand", value: "RIGHT" },
    { label: "Left Hand", value: "LEFT" }
  ]}
/>
<MyComponent
  options<Gender>={[ // <--- this syntax is wrong
    { label: "Male", value: "MALE" },
    { label: "Female", value: "FEMALE" }
  ]}
/>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After I have read the [official typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) I would suggest the following:

```
function MyComponent<T>(props: {
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: T;
  }[];
}) {
  return <div>MyComponent</div>;
}


type DominantHand = "RIGHT" | "LEFT";

function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <MyComponent<DominantHand>
      options={[
        { label: "Right Hand", value: "RIGHT" },
        { label: "Left Hand", value: "LEFT" },
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have the generic defined within the interface itself so it can be passed down to the object inside.

so it should be like this:

```
interface Props<T> {
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: T;
  }[]
}
function MyComponent(props: Props<string>) {...}
```

Comment: But I want `MyComponent` to be flexible depending on where it's used. This forces it to a `string`, and essentially is the same as not using a generic type at all.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle, you can pass any type you want, i just put a string to clarify it to, you can replace the `string` with any type it could be `number` or `boolean` or any type you have declared, ex: if you defined type `type SampleType = { key: string; anotherKey: boolean;  }` so you pass it as well: `Props<SampleType>`, `Props<boolean>` , ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
interface Props<T> {
  options: <T>[]
}
```

And then you can create a seperate options object and pass it like this

```
interface GenericPropObject {
....
}

function MyComponent(props: Props<GenericPropObject>) {...}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this, could you show an example of how I can take the same `MyComponent` component and use it with two different generic types?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat **advanced** way to do it (which I did in the current project I am working on)

Here, I have a React component `TextInput` which displays inputs of types `text`, `password`, or `email`.

But, I want to ***give anyone using this component the option to make sure the supplied*** `name` for the input ***matches their form names***.

So, My Signup Form name `types` looks like this. ( *I did it this way, so I can update the state with values from all the inputs from one function, by using the names each input component will provide on input* ).

```
type SignupInputNamesTypes =
  | "email"
  | "username"
  | "first_name"
  | "last_name"
  | "password"
  | "password_confirm"
  | "referrer";
```

Then, the `TextInput` props.

```
export interface TextInputProps<NameTypes> {
 name: NameTypes;
 type: "text" | "password" | "email";
...
...
...
}
```

Then the `TextInput` component itself

```
export default function TextInput<NameTypes>({
  label,
  name,
  value = "",
  type = "text",
  infoText = "",
  showChecked = false,
  handleChange,
  required = false,
  cssClasses,
}: TextInputProps<NameTypes>): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
     ...
     ...
     ...
    </>
)};
```

So to use the `TextInput` component, you do something like this

```
<TextInput<SignupInputNamesTypes>
          type="text"
          cssClasses="flex-1"
          value={state.first_name}
          label={__("First Name", "referrer-plugin")}
          name="first_name"
          handleChange={(value, event) => {
            handleChange("first_name", value);
          }}
          required
        />
```

**Notice** what I did here **`<TextInput<SignupInputNamesTypes>`**
I am now able to pass my `type` generic to the `TextInput` component, which is then used to set the acceptable `name` types.

And the built of this, is that its not even required to pass along the generic while using the `TextInput` component.

I hope this helps someone out there.

This is what it looks like on Storybook.

[image]